# Sql - Simple query with count

Tags: sql, select, count

I have a simple question on how to read the number of occurences of some values in a table B that references to a value in a table A. It's all explained better in the following example:

Let's say I have two simple tables, A with an attribute ID and B with an attribute ID that references A.ID; I use this code to find the number of occurences of a A.ID value into B:

```
SELECT A.ID, COUNT(*)
FROM A JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result using something like the following code...

```
SELECT ID, -- SOMETHING --
FROM A
....
```

... using this subquery?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM B WHERE B.ID = A.ID
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be referring to a correlated subquery:

```
select a.id, (select count(1) from b where id=a.id) cnt from a;
```

The `a.id` term in the subquery binds with table `a` in the outer query.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about, thank you! Can I ask you what is count(1) ? Is that related to the fact that the inner query must return 1 result?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1. Basically, there's no difference; it's a matter of preference. I prefer count(1) because the lexical context inside the aggregate function can really take any expression, and 1 is a valid expression, but * is not. The count(*) form is sort of a special form that serves no purpose. But either form works.